# Presenting relational data as columns in table

Tags: google-app-maker

Trying to figure out how to present/edit related data in a table, could really use a push in the right direction!

Broadly, this is looking at subscription data - I want to see how much each client is paying per month. If a client gets upsold halfway through the year - I need the data to reflect that.

So, I have a database of clients, and a database of months, with a Many-One relationship. I also have a "monthlyallocation" database related to both, so I can say Client A has $40 for Jun 2017, for eg. I'm looking to present the data like so in a table, and make the numbers editable:

```
             Jun   Jul   Aug   Sep 
  Client A   20    20    22    20
  Client B   15    20    15    15
  Client C   null  11    11    12
```

So I can filter out months (columns), and I can filter out Clients (rows). Any help appreciated!

************EDIT - So I've managed to get partway there.

First, the datasource for the table needs to Client - since I want my table rows to be grouped by client.

Next, the page has a custom property "datenum" which I can change to help filter out columns.

Each column header now becomes @datasources.Months.items..MonthName[@properties.datenum + **Insert Column Number Here**]. As the datenum changes, the columns display different names. Great.

The last piece of the puzzle though - the values shown IN the table need to filter by the column header name. I can't do the "[@properties.datenum + **Insert Column Number Here**]" trick here, in case I'm missing a value.. If I did that, I could accidentally get the Sep value under Aug, for eg.

Really hope that makes sense - my first instinct is to make a script that takes the rows datasource, and the "MonthName[@properties.datenum + **Insert Column Number Here**]", and return the correct value, but maybe I'm just misunderstanding how binding works and there's a simpler way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

For filtering out clients, check out this tutorial: https://developers.google.com/appmaker/tutorials/establish-relations/

It shows how to create a data query with a filter, which is basically what you need for that.

---

Filtering out columns is a bit tougher, at least I haven't figured an easy way to do it yet.

**DISCLAIMER: Out there, there are probably solutions that are much better than this one. This is just to give you a thought.**

I've solved this problem by using a custom property List named 'isVisible' for the page the table is in. Then I've added a multi select named 'ColumnPicker' into the page.

After each change in the ColumnPicker, I sync the changes with isVisible. Each column's visibility (for both header and data parts) are connected to:
`@widget.root.properties.isVisible[@widget.childIndex]`

So using the widget's index, I relate it to the isVisible list.

Here's the sync function I'm using:

```
  function syncColumnPickerValuesWithIsVisible(columnPickerWidget, newValues) {
    setIsVisibleAllSameValue(columnPickerWidget, false);
    newValues.forEach(function(element) {
      columnPickerWidget.root.properties.isVisible[element] = true;
    });
  }
```

So in the sync, I first set all isVisible values to false. Then I use the newValues array that the multi select provides to set the correct isVisible elements as true.

=> Items selected from the multi select are shown as columns in the table.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help!

I think you may have solved the hard problem (filtering columns) when I was more after a solution to the easy problem - presenting three related databases in a single table.

So the "Months" (cols) relate to the names in one database, the "Clients" (rows)relate to the names in another database, and the actual data in the table is the "monthlyallocation" database entry that relates to both columns.

Sorry, I should have left the filtering to another question, really appreciate the help there though, will be using that idea once I figure out this one!

Comment: Sorry, I was a little lazy regarding actually reading your post before answering (and wanted to give a quick answer, since I had to do actual work, too :D). Unfortunately, I'm yet to gain experience on presenting related data that way, so someone else has to weigh in.